# Can anyone give an example that clarifies the disadvantages of the "Module Revealing Pattern"?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I'm reading a book about javascript patterns. When reading about the Revealing module pattern, I get confused about the disadvantages that the pattern implies.

Aren't the disadvantages of a simple module the same as the RMP ?
Is there a code example that demostrates these disadvantages ?

I have pasted the text that talks about the downsides of this pattern, below. I am not sure how this differs from a common module.

> Disadvantages
>
> A disadvantage of this pattern is that if a private function refers to a public function, that public function can't be overridden if a patch is necessary. This is because the private function will continue to refer to the private implementation and the pattern doesn't apply to public members, only to functions.
>
> Public object members which refer to private variables are also subject to the no-patch rule notes above.
>
> As a result of this, modules created with the Revealing Module pattern may be more fragile than those created with the original Module pattern, so care should be taken during usage.

Comment: This question already has an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14098667/542251)

Comment: I stated that I didn't understood that answer. I am asking for a further explanation of this text, which is just a copy and paste of the book I am reading. Thanks anyway.