# Revealing Module Pattern And Scope

Tags: javascript, scope, revealing-module-pattern

I ran into an issue with some javascript I was running and broke it down to the code below.  I'm confused as to why the `_localVar` variable doesn't change after `init()` is called.  I find that if I reference `this._localVar` in the revealingModule, the results are as expected.  I am confused about the scope.  Could someone please clarify why this is occurring. I thought that if I didn't use `this`, then the next scope would be the module, but I don't think that's happening.

```
var myRevealingModule = (function () {
    var _localVar = "Default";

    function init() {
        console.log(_localVar);
        _localVar = "Init";
    }

    function getTest() {
        console.log(_localVar);
    }

    return {
        init: init,
        getTest: getTest,
        localVar: _localVar
    };
})();

myRevealingModule.getTest();               // "Default"
console.log(myRevealingModule.localVar);   // "Default"
myRevealingModule.init();                  // "Default"
myRevealingModule.getTest();               // "Init"
console.log(myRevealingModule.localVar);   // "Default"   * WHY *
```

Comment: The Revealing Module Pattern has a number of disadvantages. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20856718/1171180. I strongly advise against its indiscriminate use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myRevealingModule.localVar` is not a reference to the variable's value; it simply copied the string when it's created.

When you use `this.localVar`, you're using the variable in the returned object. Hence, when you change that identifier, it also updates with `myRevealingModule.localVar`.

Comment: I thought this initially, but if I use `this._localVar = "Init";` the `console.log(myRevealingModule.localVar);` now says "Init"

Answer (score 1):

Note that your module uses a self-invoking function. Therefore the value of `myRevealingModule.localVar` is determined right after the definition and built-in invocation of `myRevealingModule`. At this time the value of `_localVar` is "Default", which is copied to returned object's `localVar` property. Even if you change `_localVar` afterwards this has no effect on `myRevealingModule.localVar` anymore.

Basically the following example show the same effect:

```
var a = 42;
var b = a;
console.log(a); // 42
console.log(b); // 42
a = 84;
console.log(a); // 84
console.log(b); // 42
```

`b` copies the value of `a`. If you change `a` afterwards that has no impact on `b`.