# Confusion about how to create classes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class

In the past when creating "classes" in JavaScript, I have done it like this:

```
function Dog(name){
    this.name=name;
    this.sound = function(){
        return "Wuf";
    };
}
```

However, I just saw someone do it like this instead:

```
var Dog = (function () {
    function Dog(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    Dog.prototype.sound = function () {
        return "Wuf";
    };
    return Dog;
})();
```

Can you do it both ways, or is the way I've done it wrong? In that case, why? And what exactly is the difference between the two in terms of what we end up with? In both cases we can create an object by saying:

```
var fido = new Dog("Fido");
fido.sound();
```

I hope someone will enlighten me.

Comment: More on how to use constructor functions and prototype can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941 hope it  helps

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are two important differences between your way and theirs.

1. Wrapping in a self invoking function (`(function() { ... })();`)
2. Using the `.prototype` property over `this.` for methods.

Wrapping things in a self invoking function, then assigning the result (as defined in the `return` statement to a variable is called the [**module** pattern](https://carldanley.com/js-module-pattern/). It's a common pattern to ensure scope is more controlled.

Using `Dog.prototype.sound = function() {}` is **preferable** to `this.sound = function()`. The difference is that `Dog.prototype.sound` is defined once for all objects with the `Dog` constructor, and the `this.sound = function() {}` is defined again *for each Dog object created*.

The rule of thumb is: Things that are individual to an object (usually its properties) are to be defined on `this`, while things that are shared to all objects of the same type (usually functions) are to be defined on the prototype.

Answer (score 4):

With your code, you're creating a new function `sound` for every new `Dog` instance that's being created. Javascript's `prototype` avoids this by creating only a single function which all object instances share; basically classical inheritance.

In the second code you're showing that's just additionally wrapped in an IIFE, which doesn't do much in this case.

Answer (score 3):

The first is the *traditional* method of creating a constructor. The second an immediately invoked function expression that returns a constructor. This method allows you to keep variables within the module without leaking out into the global scope which could be an issue.

> And what exactly is the difference between the two in terms of what we end up with?

They both, as you've seen, have the same result. The others have talked about `prototype` so I won't mention it here.

Comment: There is a small difference in result. The second example can be considered better due to the use of `prototype`.

Comment: Nope, it wasn't me though.

Comment: Loving the username :)

Comment: The second isn't the revealing module pattern nor any module pattern at all. It's just setting a prototype method inside of an IIFE. To tell the difference between different implementations of the module pattern, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906662/javascript-design-pattern-difference-between-module-pattern-and-revealing-modul/22918556#22918556

Answer (score 2):

The second is preferable because it takes advantage of Javascript's prototypal inheritance mechanism.

**Prototypes**

Javascript inheritance is a cause of confusion, but it's actually fairly simple: every object has a prototype, which is an object that we will check when we try to access a property not on the original object. The prototype will, itself, have a prototype; in a simple case, like `Dog`, this will probably be `Object.prototype`.

In both of your examples, because of how the `new` [operator works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new), we will end up with a prototype chain that looks like this: `fido->Dog.prototype->Object.prototype`. So, if we try to look for the `name` property on Fido, we'll find it right there on the object. If, on the other hand, we look for the `hasOwnProperty` property, we'll fail to find it on Fido, fail to find it on `Dog.prototype`, and then reach `Object.prototype`, where we'll find it.

In the case of `sound`, your examples define it in two different places: in the first case, `fido` and every other dog we create will have their own copy of the function. In the second case, `Dog.prototype` will have a single copy of the function, which will be accessed by individual dogs when the method is called. This avoids wasting resources on storing duplicates of the `sound` function.

It also means that we can extend the prototype chain; maybe we want a `Corgi` class that inherits the `sound` function from `Dog`. In the second case, we can simply ensure that `Dog.prototype` is in `Corgi.prototype`'s prototype chain; in the first, we would need to create an actual Dog and put it in the prototype chain.