# Difference between Revealing Module Pattern and simple Constructor

Tags: javascript, revealing-module-pattern

Googled but did not find appropriate resource to explain the difference between using Revealing Module Pattern and `this` keyword.

When using revealing module pattern I can have the below code :

```
var moduleRevealing = function() {
    var talk = function() {
      console.log("Talking....");
    };
    var walk = function() {
      console.log("Walking...");
    };
    return {
      talk: talk,
      walk: walk
    }
  };

  console.log('Module Pattern Object');
  console.log(moduleRevealing());
```

Now the same thing can be achieved using `this` keyword as below:

```
var module = function() {
    var talk = function() {
      console.log("Talking....");
    };
    this.walk = function() {
      console.log("Walking...");
    };
    this.talk = talk;
  };
  var mod1 = new module();
  console.log('Module Object');
  console.log(mod1);
```

How are both different? I can only see one difference and that is the `__proto`; The former points to `Object` while the later is `module`.

In case someone want's to see the code - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mL8dr71q/1/)

Comment: That `moduleRevealing` function should not be called with `new`. Where did you find such a thing?

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for pointing that out. My mistake, corrected it. It did not make sense when I am returning an object.

Comment: Btw, yes, that prototype inheritance is all the difference between a factory function and a constructor. If there are no properties to inherit, you should use a factory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your simple example there is no difference, but let me make it just a little more complicated.

```js
var moduleRevealing = function() {
    var talk = function() {
      console.log("Talking....");
    };
    var walk = function() {
      console.log("Walking...");
    };
    var walkAndTalk = function(){
      walk();
      talk();
    };
    return {
      talk: talk,
      walk: walk,
      walkAndTalk: walkAndTalk
    }
  };
```

Using `this`,

```js
var module = function() {
    var talk = function() {
      console.log("Talking....");
    };
    this.walk = function() {
      console.log("Walking...");
    };
    this.talk = talk;
    this.walkAndTalk = function(){
      this.walk();
      this.talk();
    }
  };
```

These two slightly more complicated examples now have very different behavior when you override their methods.

```js
var modR = moduleRevealing();
var mod1 = new module();
modR.walk = function() {console.log('FAST Walking...");}
mod1.walk = function() {console.log('FAST Walking...");}

modR.walk(); // outputs "FAST Walking..."
modl.walk(); // outputs "FAST Walking..."

modR.walkAndTalk(); // outputs "Walking ... Talking..."
mod1.walkAndTalk(); // outputs "FAST Walking...Talking..."
```

Note that even though `walk()`'s output is changed When you override an instance created using Revealing Module, that change isn't picked up by the dependent method `walkAndTalk()`. The underlying reason is that the Revealing Module pattern encourages the indiscriminate use of javaScript closures for people who haven't bothered to learn `this` properly. See this [post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906662/javascript-design-pattern-difference-between-module-pattern-and-revealing-modul/22918556#22918556) for a comparison of difference between module pattern variants.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, there is effectively no difference (except for the subtleties of `constructor` etc.) Both return an object with a new copy of each method attached. If `talk` and `walk` were part of `module.prototype`, that would be different.