# revealing module vs object literal pattern on encapsulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, oop, design-patterns

I usually do component for each feature, says I have abc feature I will create below js

```
var AbcComponent = (function(){}
   var initialize = function(){

   },
   privateMethod1 = function(){

   };

   return {init:initialize}
)();
```

and include in app.js, with `AbcComponent.init();`. Few days ago I ready about OO using object literal pattern and I doubt my own writing style.

How can literal pattern encapsulate scope since javascript is function scope?

Answer (score 1):

All module patterns that need to have truly private data must inherently use an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) to maintain their own private scope. Even the object literal module pattern uses this. See a comparison of some [module patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22918556/2990144),

You can store pseudo-private data in a couple of ways with an object literal:

By convention, properties that start with an `_` underscore are understood to be off-limits to the rest of the world.

```
{
    _privateBar : 1
    publicFoo : 4,
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol).

```
const privateBar = Symbol('private');
myModule[privateBar] = 1;
myModule.publicFoo = 4;
```

Using the latter, only a reference to the `privateBar` symbol object can get you the value of `1` from `myModule`. And no, you can't get it with `myModule[Symbol('private')]`, because symbols are unique and `Symbol('private') === Symbol('private')` is `false`.

Unfortunately, they decided to add [Object.getOwnPropertySymbols()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols), so an object's symbols are not truly private and are not suitable for protecting data from malicious activity.

However, in practice, most operations you perform (`for of` loops, etc.) will not touch symbols. And therefor it is an excellent replacement for the underscore `_` convention. But sometimes there are even [better ways](https://curiosity-driven.org/private-properties-in-javascript), such as [using a WeakMap](https://github.com/sindresorhus/pkg-conf/commit/b70d12b04ff1e2812f3547e4b1f0a4bca5d9ef36).

Using ES6 we can actually avoid the slight overhead of an IIFE thanks to lexical scoping.

```
const myModule = {};

{
    const privateBar = 1;
    myModule.publicFoo = 4;
}
```

Comment: I'm asking how object literal pattern can be used for encapsulation since they are just bunch of objects.

Comment: @NatelyJamerson I added some more info, including that the so-called "object literal module pattern" still includes an IIFE for encapsulation. If this doesn't do it for you, maybe you could add some links to what you read and what you think the author means or what their code is doing. Then I can explain or correct it with more context.