# What is different between revealing module vs module patterns in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, single-page-application

Over the years I've worked on a lot of JavaScript single page applications. All these were one thing in common JavaScript MVC. I've noticed either revealing module or module pattern being used in javascript depending upon framework I used. I can see and differentiate between these patterns and how to play along. But my question is there any specific reason for choosing particular one pattern over the other one in this case?

best regards,

Comment: Please refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906662/javascript-design-pattern-difference-between-module-pattern-and-revealing-modul

Comment: If you want learn about more designing patterns then visit : https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/

Comment: addyosmani's blog I always visit that one for details. but I think first one is more relevant to my question.