# Javascript revealing module pattern disadvantages

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I have been reading about `revealing module pattern` in Addy Osmani's book. It highlights following disadvantage:

> A disadvantage of this pattern is that if a private function refers to
>   a public function, that public function can't be overridden if a patch
>   is necessary. This is because the private function will continue to
>   refer to the private implementation and the pattern doesn't apply to
>   public members, only to functions.
>
> Public object members which refer to private variables are also
>   subject to the no-patch rule notes above.
>
> As a result of this, modules created with the Revealing Module pattern
>   may be more fragile than those created with the original Module
>   pattern, so care should be taken during usage.

I'm not an expert in JS and it is not making much sense to me. Also book doesn't provide any ***examples of these disadvantage comparing to module pattern***.

I googled and found this on here:

[Revealing module pattern disadvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050755/revealing-module-pattern-disadvantages)

which again I'm not able to grasp. As examples being used are using constructor functions.

Could someone please ELI5 please.

Comment: Same question ...

Answer (score 3):

This could be understood by the code below.

```
    var myRevealingModule= (function(){

        let privateVar = 'Kirti';
        let publicVar ='Hye there';

        function getName () {
            console.log('name is ' + privateVar);
        }

        function privateGetNames(){
            getName()
            sayGreeting();
        }

        function sayGreeting() {
            console.log(publicVar);
        }

        return {
            getname: privateGetNames,
            sayGreeting: sayGreeting
        }
    })();


 //earlier result 
myRevealingModule.getname();
//overriding a public method    
myRevealingModule.sayGreeting = () => console.log('helloooo change');
    myRevealingModule.getname();
```

in this **myRevealingModule** has a private method **privateGetName** which access **sayGreeting** a public Method and now if I want to override sayGreeting later (like I did above) the privateGetName will continue to access its private sayGreeting not the overridden **sayGreeting**  that we declared later.

hence its very difficult to patch these public methods

There is a very nice article which can help you on with detailed explaination. https://developerslogblog.wordpress.com/2017/10/22/drawbacks-in-the-javascript-module-pattern/